# Logging DNS requests with iptables

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables

I need to log DNS requests for a VPN setup. The setup uses iptables to masquerade clients. I was hoping to be able to create a new iptables rule using the `LOG` target, but that just gives me output like this:

```
Dec 18 17:42:07 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 kernel: [ 2043.558931] DNS req 
IN= OUT=eth1 SRC=192.168.50.4 DST=192.168.50.5 LEN=55 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 
ID=62726 PROTO=UDP SPT=45779 DPT=53 LEN=35
```

Is there any way to make iptables add the DNS hostname to that log entry (or the entire UDP body so I can grep for it later)?

Note: I know I could use the `TEE` target to duplicate packets and send them to a custom logging daemon/DNS server, but for now I'm hoping to tweak the iptables logging options to do this instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should be pulling the logs from your DNS servers as they have this information already. There is no need for you to be doing this via iptables, even if it was capable of it.

Comment: That's too late. They'll show the VPN node's IP address, not the VPN client's IP address.

Comment: so you would then just have an extra step of correlating your vpn's logs that maps the client IP to the vpn provided IP to the IP you see in your DNS logs.

Comment: No because multiple clients will all connect to the same VPN node and will share its IP. Anyway I'm not looking for advice on the approach. I'm just looking for answer to my question.

Comment: Trying to help you come up with a solution since IPtables does not read that far into the packets. You'll either want something on that server that does, or correlate logs by logging dns connections and matching that up with dns request logs.

Comment: OK don't worry I think I'll use TEE to send packets to tcpdump instead. Thanks anyway.